# Building a constexpr template struct (C++11)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, constexpr

I have this code, which works... so far so good :

```
struct _TYPEIDSTR {};
typedef _TYPEIDSTR *TYPE_ID;
template<class T> _TYPEIDSTR _TYPE_ID;

template<class T> constexpr TYPE_ID getTypeID() { return &_TYPE_ID<T>; }
```

calling in main like this :

```
constexpr TYPE_ID id1 = getTypeID<int>();
constexpr TYPE_ID id2 = getTypeID<int>();
RLOG("ID1 : " << id1);
RLOG("ID2 : " << id2);
```

works perfectly, and I've an unique identifier for each type used in getTypeID() call.
Now I want to build a struct that brings some info about a function :

```
template<typename RES, typename... ARGS> struct _GlobalOverlayInfo {
    bool _member;
    RES(*_fn)(ARGS...);
    size_t _nargs;
    TYPE_ID _argIDs;
    constexpr _GlobalOverlayInfo(RES(*fn)(ARGS...)) :
    _member(false),
    _fn(fn),
    _nargs(sizeof...(ARGS)),
    _argIDs {getTypeID<ARGS>()...}
    {}
};

template<typename RES, typename... ARGS>
constexpr auto getOverlayInfo(RES(*fn)(ARGS...)) {
    return & _GlobalOverlayInfo<RES, ARGS...>(fn); <<---ERROR1
}
```

using this function :

```
int pippo(int x) {
    return 0;
}
```

and calling like this :

```
constexpr auto x = getOverlayInfo(pippo); <<--- ERROR2
```

I get the 2 marked errors; ERROR1 is "taking address of a temporary" (but shouldn't it a compile time evaluation ?) and ERROR2 is "error: ‘&’ is not a constant expression".
I tried in many ways, but I couldn't success. Where I am wrong ?
Is there a way (in C++11) to achieve this result ?
All I need is a pointer to an unique structure generated for each RES and ARGS... parameters.

Comment: Template variables (`_TYPE_ID`) are a C++14 feature; do you accept a C++14 answer?

Comment: uhmm... I'm testing on C++14 but it should run on C++11. But if it's worth the effort I could try to rebuild the toolchain for my microcontroller with newer GCC. I need to spare RAM as possible, so I need these info at compile time to have them in flash memory.

Comment: not sure to understand: do you need a conpile-time identificator referring to the **type** or the (dependant from `pippo`) object?

Comment: I'll try to explain better: do you want the same identifier from `_GlobalOverlayInfo` if you initialize it with different functions or you want different identifiers from objects initialized with `pippo()` and with `pluto()`?

Comment: Returning an address of a temporary doesn't make much sense in practice. I think it also formally prevents your `constexpr` function from actually being evaluated at compile time. You may want to return `_GlobalOverlayInfo` by value instead. Taking a step back, it's not clear why you think you need `_GlobalOverlayInfo` at compile time; you should be able to get to everything you need via type traits and similar metaprogramming techniques. It appears you are trying to implement some form of run-time type information (RTTI) - but then your insistence on `constexpr` is puzzling.

Comment: My problem is that I'm working on a microcontroller with few RAM... so I need all type info compiled statically in flash. By now I managed to reduce RAM usage for each binding from 200 bytes to 36 bytes, which means some 30 KBytes RAM lost with the amount of bindings I have.
Having this struct statically in flash memory I can lower the usage to 16 Bytes/binding, lowering RAM usage to 40% of actual.
To clarify, the system uses a sort of Function<>("name", func) to connect C++ functions to the scripting engine. This struct stores all needed data to perform the actual call.

Comment: @max66, I need a different struct for each different function. The struct contains both function type info and function pointer.

Comment: Names beginning with an _Underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the compiler and official libraries. If I remember correctly. I never use leading underscores or capital letters.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand what you want to do.

Anyway, if you want to works with C++11 (and avoid C++14 or newer) you can't use a template variable like

```
template<class T> _TYPEIDSTR _TYPE_ID;
```

that is a C++14 feature.

If you want a `constexpr` template identifier, you could use `std::type_index`, that is available starting from C++11.

If you can't use `std::type_index`... well, the best I can imagine is a template class with a `static` variable and a `static` method that return the pointer to it.

Something like

```
template <typename>
struct typeId
 {
   static constexpr int const val {};

   static constexpr int const * getId ()
    { return &val; }
 };

template <typename T>
constexpr int const typeId<T>::val;
```

You can get `constexpr` values and you can check that are differents

```
constexpr auto const idInt = typeId<int>::getId();
constexpr auto const idLong = typeId<long>::getId();

std::cout << (idInt != idLong) << std::endl; // print 1
```

For the function case...

Functions has types and single functions can be template parameters.

So if you want a `constexpr` identifier for a function, you can create a wrapper as follows

```
template <typename Ft, Ft f>
struct funcT
 { };
```

and, using the preceding `typeId`, get different `constexpr` values from different functions as follows

```
int  foo (int) { return 0; }
int  bar (int) { return 0; }
long baz (int, long, long long) { return 0L; }

// ...

constexpr auto idFoo = typeId<funcT<decltype(&foo), &foo>>::getId();
constexpr auto idBar = typeId<funcT<decltype(&bar), &bar>>::getId();
constexpr auto idBaz = typeId<funcT<decltype(&baz), &baz>>::getId();

std::cout << (idFoo != idBar) << std::endl; // print 1
std::cout << (idFoo != idBaz) << std::endl; // print 1
```

Comment: I like your idea with an external `funcT` which provides the `getId` functionality. I guess this approach might be extended to cover both cases: types and functions. That way, there would be no need to modify all types (which might not be possible).

Comment: To clarify, I need a structure created in PROGRAM MEMORY (aka Flash, in my case), containing some info about function params and return value, a function pointer with the address and some other minor stuffs.
I already have it, but in RAM, which is not optimal for my purposes
The final result is to have a template that called like this:
`Func("name", function)`
will return a pointer of such a structure which will be stored (this time in RAM at runtime) in an array along with "name" pointer.
All is working now, besides a way to place the structure in flash memory at compile time.